# Convert to different number base?

Tags: number-systems

If I have the number:

$$ 0.67 \cdot 7^{-6}$$ in base **10**, what will the converted value in base $7$ be?

I am finding it difficult in understand the logic of conversion, can someone give any guidance on how it works? I believe the value cant be the same since the digits will range in $[0, 6]$

Comment: Perform [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Method) $\frac{67}{100}$, but in base $7$ and shift right by two digits after decimal point. The result should be similar to [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+67%2F100+to+base7)

Answer (score 3):

We have:

- $67\times7=\color{red}4\times100+69$;
- $69\times7=\color{red}4\times100+83$;
- $83\times7=\color{red}5\times100+81$;
- $81\times7=\color{red}5\times100+67$.

Since the remainder $67$ had already occurred, things now enter into a cycle, and therefore $0.67$ is represented in base $7$ as $0.445\,544\,554\,455\ldots$ and therefore $0.67\times7^{-6}$ is represented by $0.000\,000\,445\,544\,554\ldots$